# Type inference for parameterized types in case of cyclic Builder scenario

Tags: kotlin

Assuming there exists the following java class:

```
public class Test {
    static class Builder<B extends Builder<B>>{
        B asBuilder() {
            return (B) this;
        }
    }

    public static <B extends Builder<B>> B newBuilder() {
        return new Builder<B>().asBuilder();
    }
}
```

Trying to call `Test.newBuilder()` in a consuming Kotlin code gives the error `Type expected`.

`Test.newBuilder<>()` has the same issue. `Test.newBuilder<Test.Builder>()` gives the error: `One type argument expected for class Builder<B : Test.Builder<B!>!>`. Since the type argument is a recursive call this can't be solved in the above fashion.

I believe this is a rather weird behavior even from Java perspective. It's strange that the Test class code was even allowed in its current form. Unfortunately, the above was a simplified version of another class that I have no control of. In reality I am trying to do

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.GelfLayout.newBuilder()
```

Comment: You seem to be able to call this from Kotlin only if you know the *exact subclass of `Builder`* that it casts itself into.

Comment: If I understand correctly, using it from Java seems to rely on raw types, which aren't available in Kotlin (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce right. I believe in the current instance the Builder is circumventing the type system to return a raw type. Kotlin doesn't seem to play well with it.